# MySQL remote connection database

Tags: mysql, localhost, ip, external

I have a tiny problem.
I created a server running on local IP 192.168.1.110. The external IP will call it 'X'.
The problem is that I can connect to server within the network but I cannot connect to my server from external IP.
I granted the permission of that specific user to everything with hostname set to "%".
Port forwarding is done for TCP/UDP.
I want to be able to connect with a phone to the database directly without SSH, so direct TCP/IP (the way I can connect locally but from external)

Comment: Did you also allow port 3306 (i assume) through your firewall?

Comment: Port forwarding should be all you need.

Comment: Yes, in port forward is port 3306 public and private ticked

Comment: do you set the bind-address to 0.0.0.0 in the /etc/my.cnf to accept connections from every IP ?

Comment: I am on windows, so I opened the folder from %ProgramData%/Mysql8.0/MySQL.ini and added a line bind-address=0.0.0.0. I checked in the program by going to option file/networking/(bottom scrolling) and address is 0.0.0.0. That, unfortunately still does not let me connect from outside my house...

Comment: can you install "nmap" on an external compputer. with this you can scan your external server IP an you can see witch ports are open.

Comment: You can also use a online tool like : https://pentest-tools.com/network-vulnerability-scanning/tcp-port-scanner-online-nmap#

Comment: @BerndBuffen So, the online tool shown me no open ports, while the zenmap discovered 5 tcp ports(445,139,135,557,2179). For scaning i used the computer that is in the network with the same ip it scanned (i don’t think this should be a problem)

Comment: Whe i you correct understand is the "client" computer in the same local netwowork "192.168.x.x" . then it is a problem. The router sees the the destination (external) IP is in the router an the they will NOT route externaly.
o you have also a Webserver on your MySQL Computer ? with this you can easy see if you can reach them (Port 80)

Comment: which kind of internet connection do you have ? DSL Fiber IPV6 light

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218240/discussion-between-seeven-and-bernd-buffen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I found the problem... It was My router...
Guys at planet had the best idea to have a 'port filter' button above (it was ticked). Of course, it was filtering the ports instead of opening them... This is how you waste 6 hours...